# Why is $http undefined in my factory?

Tags: angularjs

**EDIT: This question is deprecated.** Please see [How to set a variable from an $http call then use it in the rest of the application WITHOUT making the whole application asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129638/how-to-set-a-variable-from-an-http-call-then-use-it-in-the-rest-of-the-applicat) instead.

I have a `factory` but `$http` is undefined. I thought DI would define it for me.

What am I doing wrong? What fundamental misunderstanding of Angular am I guilty of here?

The extra parens `()` is causing the function to be called during the configuration phase I guess. But `URL` is a property I want available right away for the whole application.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Test',['$http'],
  {
    URL: (function ($http) {
      $http.get('http:www.myserver.com/api/thing').then(function (response) { });
    })() // extra parens makes the function run right off the bat
  }
);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `// extra parens makes the function run right off the bat` and it makes it set the `URL` property to undefined...

Comment: HINT: When you use that array syntax to specify the dependencies, the last item in the array needs to be a function:  `angular.module('myApp').factory('Test', ['$http', function($http) { ... });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory definition is wrong.  Using the inline dependency injection style that you have, the second argument should be an array whose last element is the function that consumes the previous dependencies

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('Test', ['$http', function ($http) {
        //return an object that represents your service's API
        return { 
            URL: function () {
              $http.get('http:www.myserver.com/api/thing').then(function (response) { });
            } //pass the actual function to invoke later
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax doesn't look quite right. Try something like this

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Test',['$http', function($http) {
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

looks to me like your syntax is wrong, should be:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Test',['$http',function($http){
    return { 
        URL: function () {
          $http.get('http:www.myserver.com/api/thing').then(function (response) { });
        } //pass the actual function to invoke later
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Almost. Just remove the quotes from `$http` inside the function params

Comment: It's still undefined. I listed this `Test` service as a dependency of a controller and tried to use `Test.URL` in the controller. The `$http` gets hit before the controller line that uses it, and it's still undefined.

Comment: The syntax is still wrong here. `URL: ` doesn't appear to be inside an object literal, it's directly in the functinon body.

Comment: I upvoted it because I knew how much effort went into it anyway.